# Java Detect Microsoft Remote Desktop Disconnection

Tags: java, remote-desktop

I have a Java program running on a Windows remote server, which I monitor through Microsoft Remote Desktop.  If the remote connection gets severed, I want the program to wait a period of time to see if the connection gets reestablished, and if not, to terminate the program in an orderly fashion.  How can I set up the program to monitor and respond to the state of the remote connection?

Comment: https://guacamole.apache.org/

Answer (score 0):

The best approaches to solving this would be to monitor various system resources that a remote connection would make such as network activity, processes, etc. For example, figure out what port remote connections run on *(I think it's 3389?)* and actively monitor that port for connections/disconnections.

Check out [pCap4J](https://www.pcap4j.org/), a library that will help monitor network activity.

(ps: for what it's worth, a solution written in C or any other low level language would be a lot more productive)